# How can I fix this "Control must be added to the page first " issue in Flet?

Tags: python, flet

A lot of this code is just shorter but the basis of this code is to show the Navigation drawer when I hit the menu button. But all I keep getting is a "Control must be added to the page first" error. I know it's the `show_drawer` method being updated before it's being added to the page, but I have no clue on what to do since I've already added it to the main.

```
from flet import *
from sidebar.sidebar import ModernNavBar

class NavigationPanel(UserControl):
def __init__(self, page):
    super().__init__()
    self.page = page
    self.drawer = NavigationDrawer(
        indicator_shape=None,
        controls=[
            Container(
                height=200,
                bgcolor='BLUE900',
                content=Text("Welcome!", weight='BOLD', size=20),
                margin=10,
                padding=10,
                border_radius=10,
                alignment=alignment.center,
                on_click=lambda e: print("Clickable without Ink clicked!"),
            ),
            ModernNavBar(),
        ]
    )
    # self.page.drawer = self.drawer

def show_drawer(self, e):
    self.drawer.open = True
    self.drawer.update()
    print('Beans')


def ApBr(self):
    return AppBar(
        title=Text('Main', weight='bold', size=18, color='WHITE'),
        # leading_width=30,
        leading=IconButton(icons.MENU, on_click=self.show_drawer),
        bgcolor='BLUE800'
    )

def build(self):
    return self.ApBr()

def main(page: Page):
  page.title = 'Hello'
  page.horizontal_alignment = 'center'
  page.vertical_alignment = 'center'
  page.window_width = 400
  page.window_height = 800
  page.theme_mode = ThemeMode.DARK

 menu = NavigationPanel(page)

def route_change(e: RouteChangeEvent) -> None:
    page.views.clear()

    page.views.append(
        View(
            route='/',
            controls=[
                Text(value='MENU', size=50, color='white', font_family='bl'),
                IconButton(
                    icon=icons.NAVIGATE_NEXT,
                    icon_color="blue400",
                    icon_size=40,
                    tooltip="Open",
                    on_click=lambda _: page.go('/main'))],
            vertical_alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
            horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
            spacing=26,
        ),

    )

    # Account View
    if page.route == "/main":
        page.views.append(
            View(
                route='/main',
                controls=[
                    menu.ApBr(),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                        icon=icons.ARROW_BACK_IOS_ROUNDED,
                        bgcolor='BLUE900',
                        on_click=lambda _: page.go('/')
                    ),
                    Text(
                        value='Hello',
                        # weight='BOLD',
                        size=25,
                        text_align=TextAlign.CENTER
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        "Drawer",
                        on_click=menu.show_drawer),
                ],
                vertical_alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
            )
        )

page.update()

def view_pop(e: ViewPopEvent) -> None:
    page.views.pop()
    top_view: View = page.views[-1]
    page.go(top_view.route)

page.on_route_change = route_change
page.on_view_pop = view_pop
page.go(page.route)

app(target=main)
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution was assign `page.drawer` to a variable `page.drawer = page_drawer` after the final `page.update()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply...But my major problem is the only way i can access the navigation drawer is if i go back to the main page then go into the page again to see its working....this could be because of the last function that pops the last page..i think

Answer (score -1):

Add a `navigation_menu = menu.drawer` then  `navigation_menu` at each page. Uncomment the commented variable `self.page.drawer = self.drawer` then finally remove `page.views.clear`